# ¿Es "no sabía qué hubiera preferido para ella" un caso de alternancia?

Tags: subjuntivo, condicional

> No sabía qué **hubiera preferido** para ella.

¿Me podríais por favor confirmar (o negar) lo que pienso? ¿"*Hubiera preferido*" es un caso de alternancia aquí? ¿Debería ser "*habría preferido*"?

Comment: ¿Qué significa "alternancia" en este contexto? En principio se debería usar el condicional, pero es sumamente común que se use el subjuntivo en su lugar.

Comment: @Pablo: quería decir que creo que se debería utilizar habría preferido pero el autor emplea el subjuntivo en vez del condicional. no entiendo por qué da preferencia a este modo... =(

Comment: En la práctica, creo que las dos formas son más o menos equivalentes, pero yo pienso que podría haber una leve diferencia: *Habría* tal vez se oye un poco más sólido, más definido, y *hubiera* podría expresar algo más tentativo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las dos formas que mencionas (con subjuntivo y con condicional) se consideran actualmente aceptables, y están en uso habitual, [según el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=uqFr1XT7vD6KF3oDZL) (sección 1.1.2.b). En el DPD se habla del asunto dentro del uso de *si*, pero obviamente esto es extrapolable a todo tipo de oraciones.

> **b)** Si la condición se refiere al pasado, la prótasis va en pretérito
>   pluscuamperfecto o antepretérito de subjuntivo y en la apódosis se
>   emplea este mismo tiempo, preferentemente la forma en *-ra*, aunque
>   también se admite la forma en *-se*: *Si hubiera/hubiese tenido dinero,
>   me hubiera/hubiese comprado un coche*; el condicional compuesto o
>   antepospretérito: *Si hubieras/hubieses estudiado, habrías aprobado*; o
>   el condicional simple o pospretérito: *Si hubiera/hubiese terminado los
>   estudios, hoy tendría un trabajo mejor*.

Es interesante leer también el punto anterior (1.1.2.a), donde se comentan otras formas correctas e incorrectas en construcciones condicionales hipotéticas.

Personalmente yo uso y oigo más el subjuntivo que el condicional en estos casos (como en el ejemplo que das), aunque cuando escribo más propiamente cuido de usar el condicional.